# Open Street Maps offline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

How to add .osm File in QGIS? Actually I know how we can add it from the vector layer but the map I want that not showen by here, it just shows maps shapefile. I want to use map offline. How can I use Open Street Maps offline?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314423/qfield-1-0-0-how-to-clip-and-use-a-google-satellite-hybrid-basemap-offline for methods.  Here's some additional links: https://qfield.org/docs/synchronise/basemaps.html, https://cloud.onpoz.com/en/blog/data/create-and-use-offline-maps/ and there is then simple approach of creating a map with the OSM basemap (even if that is the only content) and exporting that to a tif or other raster.